# MongoDB and Node.js: Check if an e-mail is in use

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm fairly new to Node.js and asynchronous functions, so I can't really get myself to make a callback or a "promise" work properly. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
async function emailQuery() {
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
    const dbo = db.db("nemalp");
    const data = await dbo.collection("ids").find({ email: email }).toArray()
    return data;
}

async function emailValidate() {
    try {
        const extract = await emailQuery();
        console.log("Records: " + extract.length);
        if (extract.length !== 0) {
            result.push("email-taken");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("Done!");
}
emailValidate();
```

The `email` variable has already been set, as well as the `result` one, which is an array, containing strings that are returned to an Ajax call and indicates which inputs made by the user are problematic. It could already contain values during the execution of the function above. All I want to do is update it. I tried to use a "callback" function to continue the execution of the code after this check is done. Unfortunately, I didn't have much success, the `result` variable remained the same.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: How are you checking whether *result* has been populated?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by populated but I will assume that it means if it was updated? Well, I didn't include the `console.log(result)` lines here to make it look clearer but on my code, I run this line two times - during `emailValidate()` and after. The problem is that while it gets printed in the console, once it runs outside the `emailValidate()` function, it's back to its original state.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are understand promises incorrectly. Promises are resolved once all sync code has been executed, unless you `await` it, in which case it resolves it right away. So the sync code executes --> causes result to be empty, and only then, resolves the Promise (`emailValidate()`), which then outputs the desired state.

Comment: I'm still confused... a lot... that will be a painful night...

Comment: Imagine async processes to be travelling to the moon. In other words, you don't want to do it, unless you really have to. So, all "sync" processes (vanilla javascript) should be done before you take yourself to the moon because they are extremely fast, compared to the async process. Now, once your Promise is resolving, those on earth don't need to wait for you to come back to get back to work. That is, unless you specifically request for them to "await" your return. In other words, Promises run in the background, so that your machine can accommodate "normal" javascript.

Comment: So... is there a way to tell them to behave like the others because they seem to be making me really upset right now?

Comment: You can wrap up emailValidate() and result inside another async function, then simply await each Promise.